# Creating an unlock/lock page feature

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create something like a lock and unlock pages feature. The user has to go thorugh the pages in this order:

```
$steps = array(1 =>'create_session.php',2 => 'QandATable.php',3 => 'individualmarks.php',4 => 'penalty.php',5 => 'penaltymarks',6 => 'complete.php');
```

So what should happen is that if the user is on a page a they SHOULD BE on, then that page shold be unlocked (or in other words the if statement is met where it shows the page's code), if the user accesses a page which they should not be on, then that page beocmes locked (the else statement is met where it displays the div with the `Continue` hyperlink`).

The problem is that even though the user is on the correct page, the page is still "locked" when it should be unlocked so the user can use the page. At moment all pages accessed are locked so my question is that how can I unlock a page when the user is on a correct page?

Below is an example create_session.php:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include ('steps.php'); //exteranlised steps.php
?>
<head>
...

</head>
<body>

<?php
if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))) { //checks if user is logged in
    if (allowed_in() === "Allowed") {
        //create_session.php code:
    } else {
        $page = allowed_in() + 1;
?>
 <div class="boxed">
<a href="<?php echo $steps[$page] ?>">Continue with Current Assessment</a>
<?php
    }

} else {
    echo "Please Login to Access this Page | <a href='./teacherlogin.php'>Login</a>";
    //show above echo if user is not logged in
}
?>
```

Below is the full steps.php:

```
<?php

$steps = array(1 =>'create_session.php',2 => 'QandATable.php',3 => 'individualmarks.php',4 => 'penalty.php',5 => 'penaltymarks',6 => 'complete.php');

function allowed_in($steps = array()){
// Track $latestStep in either a session variable
// $currentStep will be dependent upon the page you're on

if(isset($_SESSION['latestStep'])){
   $latestStep = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
}
else{
   $latestStep = 0;
}
$currentStep = basename(__FILE__); 

$currentIdx = array_search($currentStep, $steps);
$latestIdx = array_search($latestStep, $steps);

if ($currentIdx - $latestIdx == 1 )
    {
       $currentIdx = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
       return 'Allowed';
    }
    return $latestIdx;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple, seems that you are over complicating the goal.  It seems like you simply want to ensure that the user completes previous steps of a process before they can continue on to the next.  Why not try something more like...

```
// General Idea
$completedArr = array('1' => false, '2' => false ...);
$pageMap = array('page1.php' => '1', 'page2.php' => '2' ...);

// On Page1
$completedArr = $_SESSION['completedArr'];
$locked = true;
$currentStep = $pageMap[$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']];  // '1'
if($currentStep > 1)
{
    if($completedArr[$currentStep - 1] === true)
        $locked = false;
}
else
{
    $locked = false;
}

$completedArr[$currentStep] = true;
$_SESSION['completedArr'] = $completedArr;
```

Use this as needed for continuous pages also.  The idea is that the pageMap you would define to give index numbers to script names.  Then you would simply check to see that the previous index was marked as completed before "unlocking" this page.

Comment: upvoted answer, I will give this and the other answer a go and see how it goes, thanks very much

Comment: Do you want me to keep my $allowed_id() function or remove that? if you have time can you paste the code I provdied in your question and state where I should make change and what I should keep to make it easier or me?

Comment: The allowed ID would most likely be depreciated with my code.  The example (which may require small tweaks to fit properly) is a stand alone solution.  It simply contains an array of "what is finished" in the session variables along with a map of page name = index # to compare things to.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, though this probably won't work as is:

```
$allowed_page = $_SESSION['latestStep'];
if ($steps[$allowed_page] == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) {
   ... allowed to be here ...
}
```

Basically, given your array of "steps", you store the index of the allowed page in the session as you. As they complete a page and "unlock" the next page, you increment that index value in your session and redirect to the next page in the sequence.

```
if ($page_is_done) {
    $_SESSION['latestStep']++;
    header("Location: " . $steps[$_SESSION['latestStep']]);
}
```

Comment: upvoted answer, I will give this and the other answer a go and see how it goes, thanks very much

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, Im assuming your first block of code goes in the create_session.php page (and other pages found in the array) with `  if (allowed_in() === "Allowed") {
        //create_session.php code:...` going inside the brackets? For second block of code Im assuming that goes in steps.php but what should the `$page_is_done` suppose to be?